# Polygon with a hole in the middle with HTML5's canvas

Tags: html, geometry, html5-canvas

Using the `<canvas>` tag I need to be able to draw a hole in a polygon.

Right now I have something very simple that uses beginPath() then does lineTo() for each point. It is then filled with fill().

I cannot see any way to have a filled polygon with a unfilled middle though, like a donut.
I'm not making a donut but it is suitable for this example.

Is there something I am missing?
I would rather not draw it fully filled then have to redraw the middle.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a donut ? Donuts are great !
please refer to this link to draw shapes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: i agree with donuts being worth a draw.  This link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp can be usefull too.

Comment: Just for clarification, I'm drawing a complex polygon with hundreds of points. A donut is just an analogy for having a hole in the middle of a polygon.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is what i made it work:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");     
ctx.beginPath();

//polygon1--- usually the outside polygon, must be clockwise
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(0, 200);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx.closePath();

//polygon2 --- usually hole,must be counter-clockwise 
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(10,100);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(100, 10);
ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
ctx.closePath();

//  add as many holes as you want
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

The main idea here is you can only use beginPath once; the outside polygon must be clockwise and holes must be counter-clockwise.

Comment: It works perfect, but I'm now wondering is there any chance to order the points in clockwise or counter-clockwise order. I found some algorithms but none of them doesn't work with non-convex polygons.

Comment: It seems to me that the orientations don't have to be CW for the outer poly and CCW for the hole – they just have to be opposite. The context assumes the orientation of the first input polygon as the _right_ one, at least in Chrome.

Comment: If someone renders GeoJSON polygons, it works well without reordering the points. I guess, the editors reorder them properly.

Answer (score 33):

Your have 2 choices to draw holes with HTML5 canvas.

**Choice 1:

Draw outer shape and inner shape in different clock direction.**

Outer shape clockwise and inner shape anti clockwise.
Or outer shape clockwise and inner shape anti clockwise.

```
ctx.beginPath();
//outer shape, clockwise
ctx.moveTo(100,20);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.lineTo(20,200);
ctx.closePath();
//inner shape (hole), counter-clockwise
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(70,170);
ctx.lineTo(140,170);
ctx.closePath();
//fill
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
```

It's a little pain to detect the shape drawing direction when we are coding.

If you need to detect whether a series of dots is clockwise or not, here is a good function:

```
function isClockwise(dots){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=1, n=dots.length; i<n; i++){
        sum += (dots[i][0] - dots[i-1][0]) * (dots[i][1] + dots[i-1][1]);
    }
    sum += (dots[0][0] - dots[n-1][0]) * (dots[0][1] + dots[n-1][1]);
    return sum < 0;
}
console.log(isClockwise([[100,20], [200,200], [20,200]]));  //true
console.log(isClockwise([[100,20], [20,200], [200,200]]));  //false
```

If your dots is clockwise but you need counter-clockwise, .reverse() your dots array.

```
var dots = [[100,20], [200,200], [20,200]];
dots.reverse();
```

---

**Choice 2:

Use 'evenodd' fill rule, draw your shapes in any direction.**
This way is much simpler than the choice 1.
    see [fill() method API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill):

```
   void ctx.fill();
   void ctx.fill(fillRule);
   void ctx.fill(path, fillRule);
```

**fillRule** can be **"nonzero"** or **"evenodd"**
 "nonzero": The non-zero winding rule, which is the default rule.
 "evenodd": The even-odd winding rule.

```
ctx.beginPath();
//outer shape, any direction, this sample is clockwise
ctx.moveTo(100,20);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.lineTo(20,200);
ctx.closePath();
//inner shape (hole), any direction, this sample is clockwise
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(140,170);
ctx.lineTo(70,170);
ctx.closePath();
//fill
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.mozFillRule = 'evenodd'; //for old firefox 1~30
ctx.fill('evenodd'); //for firefox 31+, IE 11+, chrome
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use [evenodd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule) fill rule: `fill('evenodd')`

[image: Even-odd rule]

```js
// properties
// - outer square
var outerLength = 200;
// - inner length
var innerLength = outerLength / 2;

// cnavas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var width = canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
var height = canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// path
// - outer square
context.rect(
  (width - outerLength) / 2,
  (height - outerLength) / 2,
  outerLength,
  outerLength
);
// - inner square
var x0 = (width - innerLength) / 2;
var y0 = (height - innerLength) / 2;
context.moveTo(x0, y0);
context.rect(
  x0,
  y0,
  innerLength,
  innerLength
);

// draw
// - stroke
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.stroke();
// - fill
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fill('evenodd');
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"><canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw your shape in a clockwise direction (for example). Then you can increase or decrease the radius and go in an anti-clockwise direction.

EDIT: Here's a very simple example of a donut:

```
<canvas id="cvs" width="300" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>

<script>
    // Get the context
    context = document.getElementById('cvs').getContext('2d');
    
    // Start a new path
    context.beginPath();
    
    // Draw a circle with a radius of 100 in the
    // clockwise direction
    context.arc(150,150,100,0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    
    // Now draw another circle with a smaller
    // radius and in the anti-clockwise direction
    context.arc(150,150,60,2 * Math.PI, 0, true);
    
    // Fill the resultant shape
    context.fill();
</script>
```

There a demonstration of the result on this page:

https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/reference/arc.html#how-to-draw-a-donut-shape

To help understand it it can be useful to change the `context.fill()` to `context.stroke()` and change both of the `2 * Math.PI` to `1.5 * Math.PI` This makes the example more clear.

It first draws an arc and then draws a second arc with a smaller radius in reverse - and there's a "connecting line" which is drawn implicitly (ie not by the code) from the end of the first arc to the start of the second. The path doesn't need closing but doing so causes no harm. If you're just stroking the donut and not filling it you might prefer this.

Comment: -1 for no explanation, posting ONLY a link that might potentialy become dead is not OK

Comment: The explanation is the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Not clear, how to scale and draw shape (arbitrary polygon) with bigger radius?! Polygon does not have a "radius"! How to scale such polygons?