# Broken/Incomplete Doughnut with CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I'm looking to make a responsive donought chart with CanvasJS but my client wants a "broken" donought. Like with a piece missing.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Or else, if it cannot be done, could another responsive graph library be recommended that can do this?

Thanks

EDIT:
I managed to "fake" a gap in it my setting one datapoint to transparent. However, it's not "real" as the transparent part is still a part.

See my pen
http://codepen.io/SubZane/pen/sHpey

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about canvasJS, but you can draw a polygon with inner rings in canvas, see the answer here: [Polygon with a hole in the middle with HTML5's canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618844/polygon-with-a-hole-in-the-middle-with-html5s-canvas)
You can also do it with SVG which some web mapping libs used for this purpose before the advent of the canvas element.

Comment: Thanks, but but I don't want to build my own graph/chart component. I'm looking to use an existing one...