# Can I define a rectangle in Canvas2D before drawing it?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Basically, I want to have a large rectangle and cut smaller rectangles out of it. I can draw the rectangle, then do clearRect(x, y, w, h) but it removes stuff I've drawn on previous to even creating the rectangle.

So basically, can I draw a rectangle over an image and then cut the rectangle without affecting the image underneath it? I have a small idea of using ctx.save and restore, but I can't quite get it to work - and I'm not 100% sure that's the right answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Cam

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to use paths:

1. Call `context.beginPath()`
2. Define the outer rect with `moveTo` and `lineTo` and `closePath`, going clockwise
3. Cut out the holes the same way but, going counter-clockwise
4. Call `context.fill()` to fill the rectangle without the holes.

This only works if you know all the holes from the start, though. This answer has more details for this approach:
[Polygon with a hole in the middle with HTML5's canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618844/polygon-with-a-hole-in-the-middle-with-html5s-canvas)

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my own time, I found a different solution to this problem, you can see it in the answers section of this question. Anyway, thanks so much for taking the time to explain your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to markE and Stefan for giving a solution. However, after hours of searching I found my own answer based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770000/4579474) answer. I have no idea why it works, but check out what code I used below:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.rect(400, 0, -400, 400);
ctx.fill();
```

For some reason, if you declare what shape you want to cut out first, and then draw the overlaying shape BACKWARDS (?!) over your area, it cuts out the shape. WTF Javascript? Anyways, it works :)

Comment: I guess drawing it backwards basically makes sure it's draw counter-clockwise. An alternative to this might be to call `ctx.fill('evenodd');`, see the link in my answer

Comment: [Here's why it works:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/). *The fill() method must fill all the subpaths of the current path, using fillStyle, and using the non-zero winding number rule. Open subpaths must be implicitly closed when being filled (without affecting the actual subpaths). Thus, if two overlapping but otherwise independent subpaths have opposite windings, they cancel out and result in no fill.* **But(!),** browsers are now starting to allow `evenodd` winding. If used, this would break your code. You might want to use more explicit methods for your task. ;-)