# QML: Draw geofence area on QML Map

Tags: dictionary, qml, qt5, qtlocation

Any ideas how to draw custom geofence area in QML (Qt Location module) similar to this:

[image]

Something similar to [`MapCircle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapcircle.html) or [`MapPolygon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mappolygon.html) but filled outside of the region? And have custom filling pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can play with one of MapItems, for example [MapQuickItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html) allows you put any `QML` item inside, for example I use `Canvas` for that:

```js
Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm"
}

Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
    zoomLevel: 14

    MapQuickItem {
        id: marker
        anchorPoint.x: image.width / 2
        anchorPoint.y: image.height / 2
        coordinate: map.center
        sourceItem: Canvas {
            id: image
            width: map.width
            height:  map.height
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(image.width, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(image.width, image.height);
                ctx.lineTo(0, image.height);
                ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
                ctx.moveTo(image.width/2 + 50, image.height/2);
                ctx.arc(image.width/2, image.height/2, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI,0, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
                ctx.lineWidth = 10;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention, the arc's counterclockwise is true to make a hole.
In the same way you can add images etc. But in a real project I would use some custom QQuickItem based item, just for better performance.

Comment: Wow! it works! Thanks! In real project I'll need to do 3 things: convert map coordinates to screen coordinates with `map.fromCoordinate()` method, so hole will move on pan or zoom (hole is in map coordinates). And replace circle with a polygon, and fill the area by tilted red dash lines pattern. So `Canvas` works perfect here.

Comment: Question about arc's counterclockwise: what if I want to draw arbitrary polygon? Will it work?

Comment: if you draw a shape (arc or polygon) in opposite direction then outer one it will make a hole.

Comment: I don't know how does this trick really works, [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618844/polygon-with-a-hole-in-the-middle-with-html5s-canvas) for example does the same I think.

Comment: As I have predefined polygon, then I need to define its direction somehow and draw outer line in the opposite direction. Also need to see what will happen if polygon crosses map viewport.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Link You'd mentioned also contains function to detect shape is clockwise or not. Also it shows how to fill area around the polygon, so it is possible to fill whole map or just some threshold around the polygon.

Comment: I've converted polygon map coordinates into screen coordinates and got multiple problems with above solution: polygon does not move/scale with map pan/zoom, this was easily solved however by setting correct `MapQuickItem`'s `coordinate` and `anchorPoint` properties.

Comment: 2nd problem: it works correctly only if geofence polygon fully inside the screen, if geofence polygon crosses map viewport so screen coordinates appear outside of the screen, then canvas draws incorrect polygon - is there a way to draw canvas outside of the screen? 

3rd: Not redrawn on map pan/zoom, so seems need to redraw canvas not only `onPaint` but also on map pan/zoom - will try this.

Comment: 3rd is solved by calling `canvas.requestPaint()` on map pan/zoom, however need to clear context on every repaint: `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)`. The only problem to solve is the 2nd one: if geofence polygon crosses lays out of map viewport (visible area).

Comment: 2nd is solved with QML `Map` component method call [`point fromCoordinate(coordinate coordinate, bool clipToViewPort)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#fromCoordinate-method) with `clipToViewPort` parameter set to `false`.